# Criar uma TAD para representar um dado

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados, c++11

Tenho a seguinte tarefa:

Criar um TAD (struct) para representar uma Circunferência e depois checar quais das circunferencias lidas possuem interseção entre elas.

Preciso armazenar quatro dados básicos, **id, x, y e raio**.
Penso em usar `std::<vector>` para armazenar os dados lidos (quantidade indefinida).

Estou com dificuldade na criação da TAD e como farei a leitura no main

```
//                      lib.hpp
#include <vector.h>
typedef struct{
    double id, x, y, raio;
} Circunferencia;

//  TAD
struct circVector{
    Circunferencia *circ;
    // como seria a passagem por parametro aqui?
    int calcularIntersecao(vector<Circunferencia> circ);
};

----------------

//                    main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "lib.hpp"
int main(){
    int n;
    // cria um "vetor de structs"
    vector<Circunferencia> c;
    // auxilia a leitura antes de guardar na TAD
    Circunferencia aux;
    while(cin >> n){
        cin >> aux._id;
        cin >> aux._x;
        cin >> aux._y;
        cin >> aux._raio;
        // adiciona a struct q foi lida para o vector de structs
        c.push_back(aux);
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual a dúvida?

Comment: Quero saber a "melhor forma" de criar a TAD e como fazer a leitura no main (armazenando tudo no <vector>).

Comment: Me parece uma questão muito ampla pra produzir uma resposta adequada. Só estou na dúvida se é clara antes de ser ampla.

Comment: @Maniero, consegui criar uma solucao. Devo apagar a pergunta ou postar a solução aqui?